# Covariance between random variables

Tags: probability, covariance

Analyzing math theory of random variables. Something fishy messes with my logic. Two questions:

1. When we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, to get covariance $Cov (X, Y)$ is basically to
   get how the values of X and Y move relative to each other. Is this true?
2. Because each random variable may generate potentially infinite sets of values, how can we determine the covariance over the infinite sets?

Just to recall the definition I [found](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_1_covariance_correlation.php):

$Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb E\big[(X-\mathbb E[X])(Y-\mathbb E[Y])\big]=\mathbb E[XY]-(\mathbb E[X])(\mathbb E[Y])$

Uses expected values to define the covariance. This looks OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Not quite. The covariance (more specifically, the correlation coefficient), measures how much the variables "depend" on each other *linearly*. A great correlation coefficient shows us that one variable is "almost" a linear function of the other, I.e. there is $a$ and $b$ such that $Y \approx aX+b$. If two random variables are uncorrelated, that does not mean that here is no relation of dependence between them - just that this relation cannot be a linear one.

2 - Well, you just anwered this in your question: use the expectations! We can compute expectations of random variables even if they assume an uncountable number of values.

Comment: We compute expectations based on pdf or pmf but we may also do directly in case the random variables generate finite sets. Is this true?

Comment: We can. But note that what you call "direct computation" is just a special case of the general formula using the cdf. In this case, the probability mass function is non-zero only for a finite number of points, making the calculations easy..

Comment: Some distributions don't have the cdf so we must use "direct" approach, isn't it.

Comment: Every distribution has a cdf. Maybe you are confunding it with the pmf or the pdf?

Comment: Yes, true. I was thinking on moment generating function.

Comment: "Maybe you are confusing it with the pmf or the pdf". I also heard that some distributions don't have pdf, but I never found an example. Do you maybe know if such distributions exist?

Comment: Sure. Any discrete random variable is an example. A Poisson random variable doesn't have a pdf (i.e., a probability density function). Do not confuse a pdf with a cdf (cumulative distribution function). Every RV has a cdf.

Comment: OK, but then discrete RV do have PMF, which is a substitute. If we forget the discrete probability distributions is it possible for some probability distribution not to have the PDF?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution